# InternalOAuthError discord oauth2

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, discord, passport.js, express-session

I am trying to log my users in using discord oauth2

I noticed, when clicking the authorize button multiple times, I am getting this error.

```
InternalOAuthError: Failed to fetch user's guilds
    at S:\project\node_modules\passport-discord\lib\strategy.js:108:32
    at passBackControl (S:\project\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (S:\project\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1220:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

After that I also get this error, but idk if that is important:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

I am using passport, passport-discord and express-session

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is because of the rate limit that discord has. I do not know any solution for this beside changing you passport to keep track of the amount of request made to discord.